# How to get transaction records of particular customers in descending order in PHP-MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to display the transaction records of some particular customers stored in MySQL table.

I tried the follwing:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Transaction ID</th>
  <th>Customer ID</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Date</th>
 </tr>
<?php
    $stmt0 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM customers WHERE status = ?");
    $stmt0->bind_param('i',$status);
    $stmt0->execute();
    $stmt0->store_result();
    $stmt0->bind_result($cust_id);
    while ($stmt0->fetch()) 
    {
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,description,amount,date FROM transactions WHERE cust_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC");
      $stmt->bind_param('i',$cust_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($id,$description,$amount,$date);
      while ($stmt->fetch()) 
      {
?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $cust_id; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $amount; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php 
      }
        $stmt->close();
    }
      $stmt0->close();
?>
</table>
```

It displays transactions records of the particular customers as per my requirements, but it displays records by grouping by "cust_id". I need to display them by ordering "id" in Descending order.

Please help!

Comment: you mean ordering the entire list by `id` in descending order irrespective of `cust_id`?

Comment: @pro_cheats yes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [SUB QUERIES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) and get the results in one SQL Statement itself.
Like -

```
<?php
    $stmt0 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t.id,t.description,t.amount,t.date FROM transactions t WHERE t.cust_id = (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE status = ?) ORDER BY t.id DESC");
    $stmt0->bind_param('i',$status);
    $stmt0->execute();
    $stmt0->store_result();
    $stmt0->bind_result($id,$description,$amount,$date);
    //PRINT/echo $id,$description,$amount,$date to the front end now
?>
```

This should return `$id,$description,$amount,$date` values in descending order of the `$id`.

Another way is using [SQL JOINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) (preferred over sub queries although internal execution will almost be the same)

```
$stmt0 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t.id,t.description,t.amount,t.date FROM transactions t INNER JOIN customers c on t.cust_id=c.id WHERE c.status = ? ORDER BY t.id DESC");
//rest of the code remains same
```